# Running a public image from AWS ECR in ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have successfully pushed my 3 docker images on ECR.
Configured an ECS cluster.
Created 3 task definitions for those 3 images stored in respective ECR repositories.
Now, I want to run a public image of redis on the same cluster as a different task. I tried created a task definition of the same using the following URL: [public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/redis:latest](https://public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/redis:latest)

But as soon as I run it as a new task I get the following error:

> Essential container in task exited

Any specific reason for this error or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the logs for the container? You can see them in console, when you click on the respective cluster.

Comment: E: You must specify either $REDIS_PASSWORD or $REDIS_RANDOM_PASSWORD, or $ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD. This message has been printed in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the redis image needs to either set a password (I recommend this as well) or allow it to connect to the redis cluster without a password.

To configure a password or disable passwords auth, you need to set environment variables in the image. You can read the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/redis) under the heading Configuration

Luckily, this is easy in ECS. You need to specify the [environment variable in the task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html). So either:

```
{
    "family": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "image": "",
            ...
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "yes"
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

or for a password:

```
{
    "family": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "image": "",
            ...
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "REDIS_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "your_password"
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

For more granular configuration you should read the documentation of the redis docker image I posted above.